# Can't pass the test (Kadane's algorithm)

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have to find the maximum sum within a one-dimensional array **(1 <= N <= 500000)** of integers **(|a| <= 4000)**.

If there are multiple subarrays with the same maximum sum, I have to print the shortest one. If there are multiple shortest subarrays, I have to print the leftmost one.

The code passes most of its tests, except one and I don't know where I did wrong.
[image]

The code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

vector<int> adj;
int kStart = 0, kEnd = 0;

void getOutput()
{
    ofstream output("max.out");
    output << kStart + 1 << " " << kEnd + 1;
    output.close();
}

void kadane()
{
    int max_global = INT_MIN, max_current = 0, kS = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < adj.size(); i++)
    {
        max_current += adj[i];

        if(max_current > max_global || (max_current == max_global && i - kS < kEnd - kStart))
        {
            max_global = max_current;
            kStart = kS;
            kEnd = i;
        }

        if(max_current < 0)
        {
            max_current = 0;
            kS = i + 1;
        }
    }
}

void getData()
{
    ifstream input("max.in");

    int n; input >> n;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int num; input >> num;
        adj.push_back(num);
    }

    input.close();
}

int main()
{
    getData();
    kadane();
    getOutput();

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: classic one: the input contains only `INT_MIN` or sets of integers whose sum is `INT_MIN`... simple guess.

Comment: What test has failed more precisely?

Comment: the test doesn't show what the input was nor what the output should be. I only get the error that it was a wrong output

Comment: It passes the basic example input from the wikipedia entry. You must have bad tie-breakers for this particular coding site challenge. Try making your own data sets with multiple ties.

Comment: @YSC Sum could be INT_MIN or less than that but array elements can't be INT_MIN as the constraint says `|a| <= 4000`

Comment: @Adomas _If there's more than one subsequence with the same maximum sum_ Shouldn't that be a subarray? If we were to deal with subsequence, the problem would be trivial.

Comment: The sum can go up to 2 10^10, higher than 2^31, max `int`  value

Comment: @Adomas Check for Integer overflows in the first place.

Comment: In case all integers are negative, what is the expected output?

Comment: @Brainless That would be single highest negative element. For example, for `[-4000,-3999,-1]`, the answer is `-1`. For this post, the answer would be `[3,3]`, the range of the subarray.

Comment: @Damien yes, that's the most probable cause of error to me

Comment: in "int max_global = INT_MIN, max_current = 0, kS = 0;", try using int64_t instead of int

Comment: it still doesn't pass the test, so I think its not the code, but a wrong output from the site